# Quotient ring of $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have learned in my class that quotient ring of $\mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}$.
Just from curiosity, I was interested in knowing if 
$$
\mathbb{R}[x] / (x^2 + ax + b) \cong \mathbb{C}
$$
holds for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when both roots of the polynomial are real?

Comment: The quotient is $\Bbb R^2$, $\Bbb R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ or $\Bbb C$ depending on if $b^2-4ac$ is positive, zero or negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Half of the quadratics have real roots, so the quotient ring would be $\mathbf{R}^2$.

The other half have complex roots, and $\mathbf{R}(\alpha) = \mathbf{C}$ for any nonreal complex number $\alpha$

A handful of quadratics have a double root, and the quotient ring would be $\mathbf{R}[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$.

Comment: Are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ both isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Tom: As rings? No: the former has a pair of nonzero numbers that multiply to zero. The latter has a nonzero number whose square is zero. As $\mathbf{R}$-vector spaces? Yes. As additive abelian groups? Yes.

Comment: Right. Of course! Thank you very much.